# Resolved |// Execute command in CMD [C#]

Tags: c#, .net

So basically, I Want to execute a command in cmd because i need to open Paint from it, Code i tried:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C mspaint.exe, openFileDialog1.FileName;"
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Can someone help me? I Want to execute paint with a png file choose by user.

Thanks Trevor for helping, Maybe the other code will work.

```
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/C mspaint.exe, " + openFileDialog1.FileName;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
```

Code working fine

Comment: I'm going to bet `startInfo.Arguments = "/C mspaint.exe, openFileDialog1.FileName;"` is your issue. Where does `openFileDialog1.FileName` come from? Anyways something like `startInfo.Arguments = $"/C mspaint.exe, {openFileDialog1.FileName}";` should work or `startInfo.Arguments = "/C mspaint.exe, " + openFileDialog1.FileName;`

Comment: Thanks, And yes, It is the issue. I Will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Trevor's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71592871/resolved-execute-command-in-cmd-c/72367347#comment126532508_71592871):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C mspaint.exe, " + openFileDialog1.FileName;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Answer (score 2):

To open a specific file using `mspaint` you can specify the file path as an argument (without any comma):

```
mspaint <filePath>
```

From the code you can do the following:

```cs
Process proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = $"/C mspaint.exe {openFileDialog1.FileName}",
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    }
};

proc.Start();
```